# javascript: add floats in loop

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, calculation

I have a *filter* function, based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) that hides table rows. I want to add the `float` values from the table if the row is not being hidden and then replace the original *sum* field below the table. So far I got the following, but for some reason it won't work and I can't figure out why:

```
function filter() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, origresults, origsum, newresults, newsum, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  origresults = document.getElementById("results");
  origsum = document.getElementById("sum");
  newresults = 0;
  newsum = 0.0;

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        newresults++;
        newsum += parseFloat(td);
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  origresults.innerHTML = newresults;
  origsum.innerHTML = parseFloat(newsum).toFixed(2);
}
```

It always says `NaN`, but I can't figure out why.

`newsum = parseFloat(newsum) + parseFloat(td);` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to calculate with `td` instead of `td.innerHTML`. So the [**parseFloat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function returned a `NaN` because `td` obviously contains the complete tag and not just it's content.

This works:

```
function filter() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, origresults, origsum, newresults, newsum, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  origresults = document.getElementById("results");
  origsum = document.getElementById("sum");
  newresults = 0;
  newsum = 0.0;

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        newresults++;
        newsum += parseFloat(td.innerHTML);
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  origresults.innerHTML = newresults;
  origsum.innerHTML = parseFloat(newsum).toFixed(2);
}
```